# Move fields into fieldset with field_collection module doesn't work

Tags: 7, entities

I have a node, inside this node I have a field_collection with one checkbox and 2 fields inside it. I want to move these two fields inside a fieldset to show/hide entire fieldset depending of the checkbox value.

```
function mymodule_form_testtype_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {    
    $form['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['surround_fieldset'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Sorround fieldset'),
        '#tree' => FALSE,
    );
    $form['field_test_collection']['#tree'] = FALSE;
    $form['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['surround_fieldset']['field_collection_first'] = $form['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['field_collection_first'];
    $form['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['surround_fieldset']['field_collection_second'] = $form['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['field_collection_second'];
}
```

But when I try to submit the form these two values are not saved. I tried to remove the original fields using

```
unset($form['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['field_collection_first']);
```

or hide them with

```
$form['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['field_collection_first']['#access'] = 0;
```

I also tried the "cheat" to move back these two fields in the *validate* function

```
function mymodule_article_form_testtype_node_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form_state['values']['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['field_collection_first'] = $form_state['values']['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['surround_fieldset']['field_collection_first'];
    $form_state['values']['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['field_collection_second'] = $form_state['values']['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['surround_fieldset']['field_collection_second'];
    unset($form_state['values']['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['surround_fieldset']);   

    $form['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['field_collection_first'] = $form['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['surround_fieldset']['field_collection_first'];
    $form['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['field_collection_second'] = $form['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['surround_fieldset']['field_collection_second'];
    unset($form['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['surround_fieldset']);
    $form['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['field_collection_first']['#access'] = 1;
    $form['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['field_collection_second']['#access']  = 1;
}
```

With a dpm($form_state) in the *submit* function I can see correct values in their places, but after it they're not saved.

Any idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It seems values from fields inside the field_collections are not managed as other Drupal form values.

This is the code to achieve the result:

```
function mymodule_form_testtype_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {    
    $form['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['surround_fieldset'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Sorround fieldset'),
    );
    $form['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['surround_fieldset']['field_collection_first'] = $form['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['field_collection_first'];
    unset($form['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['field_collection_first']);
    $form['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['surround_fieldset']['field_collection_second'] = $form['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['field_collection_second'];
    unset($form['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['field_collection_second']);
    $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_node_form_submit';
}

function mymodule_node_form_submit($form, &form_state) {
    $form_state['field']['field_test_collection']['und']['entity'][0]->field_collection_first['und'][0]['value']=$form_state['values']['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['surround_fieldset']['field_collection_first']['und'][0]['value']; 
    $form_state['field']['field_test_collection']['und']['entity'][0]->field_collection_second['und'][0]['value']=$form_state['values']['field_test_collection']['und'][0]['surround_fieldset']['field_collection_second']['und'][0]['value'];
}
```